# db_datareader User mapping is allowed to do Update, Create Queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

In a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, I created a user login with:

- Server Role: `Public`
- User Mapping: `master`, `model`, `msdb`
- Database Role Membership `db_datareader`, `public`

When I use with new user login to connect it connects and I can run update, create commands. Which I don't want to run.

The same setting I tried in SQL Server 2012. It didn't allowed me to run update and create commands.

I get an error :

> CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'TEMP'.

In SQL Server 2012 I have a different database.

Please give solution

I have followed this https://www.itsupportguides.com/server-side-tips/sql-management-studio-how-to-create-read-only-users/

Comment: Check if your public role has assigned additional rights.

Comment: You can script Login and user and post, to check what is exactly set.

Comment: Also, check server role membership.  In the case of a Windows login, check for additional permissions paths via group membership:  `EXEC xp_logininfo 'YourDomain\YourUser', 'all';`.

Comment: @lad2025 It gives there is no actions to be scripted. If I click for script. Public role is assigned with Endpoints->TSQL Default TCP,TSQL Default VIA,TSQL Local Machine,TSQL Named Pipes and Servers->CloudServer. Permissions for Selected Endpoints : Ticked only for Connect->Grantor:DBO->Grant.

Comment: @DanGuzman It is SQL Server Login. It EXEC xp_logininfo doesn't run in New User. It is only running in DBO with DB Owner login. I didn't any useful info from EXEC xp_logininfo.

Comment: @Ramki, xp_logininfo is only for Windows logins.  Is the sql login the database owner?  If you login with the login and switch to the `TEMP`, what does `SELECT USER;` return?

Comment: @DanGuzman it gives same User Login name which I logged in.

Comment: @Ramki, you mentioned the login isn't mapped to the TEMP database so no access to that database should be allowed by that user.  Verify no server roles with `EXEC sp_helpsrvrolemember`.

Comment: @DanGuzman Temp was other try from SQL 2012 which I have in other system. It worked fine it is not allowing Alter,Update or Create

Comment: Run the commands on the database that is not working.

Comment: @DanGuzman In a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, I created a user login with:

Server Role: Public
User Mapping: master, model, msdb
Database Role Membership db_datareader, public
When I use with new user login to connect it connects and I can run update, create commands. Which I don't want to run. These commands should not work for me. This is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

for this Login
mark SERVER Role for following Databases as db_DenyDataReader , and db_DenyDatawriter